# How can I replace a value in a likn using javascript

Tags: javascript

Please can someone help me correct this script. I want to replace

"http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=k9Gc613jTq8"

with this
(My target is to replace 'watch?v=' with 'embed')

"http://m.youtube.com/embed/k9Gc613jTq8"

I tried it this way but its not working:

var msg=document.getElementsByName("youtube"); for(var i=0;i

I'll be glad if someone can help me get it to work.

Comment: With regex `replace()`

Comment: str.replace("watch?v=","embed/");

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var link = "http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=k9Gc613jTq8";
link.replace('watch?v=','embed/');
```

Output:

```
"http://m.youtube.com/embed/k9Gc613jTq8"
```